# Issue while parsing half-width Katakana in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I have used GWT in our application. Here client send some half-width katakana string to server. Client have issue while parsing some of the strings in half-width katakana to server. So, is there any issue with GWT to parse it or to handle some katakana chars?
below are my findings:
Application work fine with string "アイウエオ"
Application crashes with string "ｶｷｸｹｺ" and "ｻｼｽｾｿ"

Have any body faced this like issue before?

Comment: It would help if you gave more information: is this about GWT-RPC ? Is there any stacktrace ? does the error happen on client or server side ?

Comment: Error happens on server side. There are two client for this server its working fine with same input on other client. But issue with my client application.

Comment: Which protocol? Which clients? You really need to give more information.